# Robocode run in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, robocode

I started to code robocode with eclipse. But whenever i run the program from eclipse it gives error,

Error: Main method not found in class robo_first.robo_new, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Things i have done:

- I added robocode.jar as a reference library

In run configuration

- VM arguments -Xmx512M -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
- Working directory other - /home/sameera/robocode
- project - robo_first
- Main class - robo_first.robo_new

What's wrong with this? Are there anything else that I should do?

```
package robo_first;

import robocode.Robot;

public class robo_new extends Robot{

    @Override
    public void run() {


        while(true){
            turnGunRight(360);
            ahead(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I ran above code in Robocode directly, by setting preference/development options and adding eclipse workspace/project/bin.. and it works..!!!

I'm using eclipse luna, ubuntu 14.04 and robocode 1.9.2.4

Comment: You should probably show robo_first.robo_new file in the question.

Comment: Thanks Aseem, I added my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error is that you are search the main method in `robo_first.robo_new`
but there is no main method in that class, you must search it in `robocode.Robocode` the class which is inheriting.

the configuration looks like this

[image]